# How to correctly import SBT Build.scala in scala-ide

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-ide

As an sbt build can be written in scala and is itself a scala project, i would like to import it in scala-ide as a scala project. For example with the following code.

Build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(id = "test",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Seq(
      organization := "com.tomahna",
      name := "demo",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.8"))
}
```

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

This build works fine with sbt, however Build.scala is not compiled by eclipse, thus i get neither compilation errors nor auto-completion.

I can add the project folder to source folders but then `import sbt._` and `import Keys._` will fail because the eclipse project is not correctly set to provide these dependencies.

Is there a way to setup the sbt project so that it interact nicely with scala-IDE ?

Comment: I used `Build.scala` in some older scala projects and everything worked fine. Could you provide some code?

Comment: Of course, my question was not clear enough. It should be better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sbteclipse manual:[link](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse)

If you want to get Eclipse support for the sbt build definition, e.g. for your Build.scala file, follow these steps:

If you are not using sbteclipse as as global plugin, which is the recommended way, but as a local plugin for your project, you first have to add sbteclipse as a plugin (addSbtPlugin(...)) to the build definition project, i.e. to project/project/plugins.sbt

In the sbt session, execute reload plugins

Set the name of the build definition project to something meaningful: set name := "sbt-build"

Execute eclipse and then reload return

Import the build definition project into Eclipse and add the root directory to the build path

Comment: Next time I'll just read the documentation till the end. Thank you very much.